# Can't set keyboard repeat rate or delay using GUI in ubuntu mate 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-15.04, mate

Usually one is able to set the keyboard repeat rate using the Control Panel GUI on Ubuntu distributions (certainly in Ubuntu Mate one can do this) however this no longer appears to be working. (Version 15.04)

I have changed the slider all the way to "shortest delay" before repeat and "fastest possible repeat rate" but there is no difference.

My guess would be this is a bug (not sure if the developers know about it or not?) and my guess would be this only affects Ubuntu MATE distributions? (Or surely it would be fixed by now.)

This is obviously a bit of a serious inconvenience for someone who does a lot of typing. Is there any way I can "trick it into changing", ie; by editing some config files (?) or by some other means?

Comment: I like to know how to do this via the command line.